# Expressão regular strsplit

Tags: r, regex

Como atribuir a E.R. para separar o nome da cidade ?

```
cid <- c(cidade1..SP.Brasil,cidade2...SP.Brasil,cidade3..SPDF.Brasil,cidade4...SPDF.Brasil)
```

No sublime por exemplo, isto funciona:

```
\\.{3}[A-Z]{4}|\\.{3}[A-Z]{2}|\\.{2}[A-Z]{4}|\\.{2}[A-Z]{2}
```

Mas não consigo atribuir a uma variável no rstudio.

```
pattern <- ".{3}[A-Z]{4}|.{3}[A-Z]{2}|.{2}[A-Z]{4}|.{2}[A-Z]{2}" 
pattern <- "\.{3}[A-Z]{4}|\.{3}[A-Z]{2}|\.{2}[A-Z]{4}|\.{2}[A-Z]{2}"
pattern <- "\\.{3}[A-Z]{4}|\\.{3}[A-Z]{2}|\\.{2}[A-Z]{4}|\\.{2}[A-Z]{2}"
pattern <- regex(".{3}[A-Z]{4}|.{3}[A-Z]{2}|.{2}[A-Z]{4}|.{2}[A-Z]{2}")
pattern <- regex("\.{3}[A-Z]{4}|\.{3}[A-Z]{2}|\.{2}[A-Z]{4}|\.{2}[A-Z]{2}")
pattern <- regex("\\.{3}[A-Z]{4}|\\.{3}[A-Z]{2}|\\.{2}[A-Z]{4}|\\.{2}[A-Z]{2}")

c <- strsplit(cid, pattern, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Você quer pegar somente o trecho `SP` ou `SPDF`?

Comment: Quero pegar só os nomes das cidades.
troquei o fixed para FALSE e funcionou, mas agora tenho uma lista :
"cidade1"   ".Brasil"
"cidade2"   ".Brasil"
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema sem regex.

```
cid  <-  c("cidade1..SP.Brasil", "cidade2...SP.Brasil", "cidade3..SPDF.Brasil", 
"cidade4...SPDF.Brasil")

primeiro <- function(x){
  return(x[[1]])
}

unlist(lapply(strsplit(cid, split="..", fixed=TRUE), FUN=primeiro))
[1] "cidade1" "cidade2" "cidade3" "cidade4"
```

Eu utilizei a sequência de caracteres ".." como separador das strings originais. Entretanto, o comando `strsplit` vai te dar como output uma lista com 4 elementos, onde cada elemento é um vetor de duas posições. Como a cidade está sempre a primeira posição deste vetor, eu criei uma função chamada `primeiro`, que vai retornar apenas o primeiro elemento de cada um destes vetores do resultado.

Os comandos `lapply` e `as.vector` são utilizados, respectivamente, para aplicar a função `primeiro` em cada elemento da lista criada pelo `strsplit` e organizar o resultado final do algoritmo em um vetor.